# Exception not fired when using TPL

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have the following code which does not fire the AggregateException
Aggregate Exception is not fired and I don't understand why? Normally it should as Aggregate exception is used to catch exceptions while running code using tasks

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Test();
            }).ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
            {
                Test2();
            });


            try
            {
                task1.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    // Handle the custom exception.
                    if (e is CustomException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                    // Rethrow any other exception.
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            throw new CustomException("This exception is expected!");
        }

        static void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test2");
        }
    }

    public class CustomException : Exception
    {
        public CustomException(String message) : base(message)
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: sure its not the debugger catching it before your code has chance?

Comment: Even if I dont use debugger the same problem. I dont get  ```This exception is expected```

Comment: Id have thought its because you used StartNew in that the error is happening before the code gets to the try for the wait

Comment: This is why you should really use `await` instead of manually adding continuations using `ContinueWith`.  One of the biggest advantages of `await` is that it propagates exceptions in a way most people would expect it to, unlike `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are waiting for completion of your continuation task (which runs `Test2()`), not for completion of task which runs `Test()`. First task fails with exception and then continuation task does nothing with this exception (you don't check if `previousTask` has failed) and completes successfully. To catch that exception you need to wait for first task or check result of it in continuation:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Test();
});
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
{
    Test2();
});
```

or

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Test();
}).ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
{
    if (previousTask.Exception != null) {
        // do something with it
        throw previousTask.Exception.GetBaseException();
    }
    Test2();
}); // note that task1 here is `ContinueWith` task, not first task
```

That's all not related of course to whether you should really do it like this or not, just to answer the question.

Comment: If an exception occurs AggregateException should be fired?

Comment: @codejunkie yes, if you run code in answer you will catch `AggregateException` is both cases.